# React onClick event not firing when it is conditionally rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a searchDropdown component in React. I want to render dropdown only when search field is active. So I put a condition to render dropdown.

But when the dropdown is rendered conditionally, `onClick` events inside dropdown are not triggering.

My component is below.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {List, ListItem} from 'material-ui/List';
import {Card} from 'material-ui/Card';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import resources from '../../resources/resources';
import cx from 'classnames';

import './SearchDropdown.scss';

class SearchDropdown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.cardContainerStyle = {
      'maxHeight': '300px',
      'overflow': 'scroll',
      'border': '1px solid rgb(158, 158,158)'
    };
    this.searchFieldUnderlineStyle = {
      'borderBottom': '1px solid #ccc'
    }
    this.state = {
      dropdownStyle: {}
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.isActive && this.props.isActive !== nextProps.isActive) {
      this.shouldSetBounds = true;
    } else {
      this.shouldSetBounds = false;
    }
  }



  componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.shouldSetBounds) {
      this._setDropdownBounds();
      this.shouldSetBounds = false;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll',  this._handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll',  this._handleScroll);
  }

  _handleScroll = () => {
    if (this.props.isActive) {
      this._setDropdownBounds();
    }
  }

  _setDropdownBounds() {
    const dropdownContainerOffset = this.dropdownContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
    const containerTop = dropdownContainerOffset.top;
    const containerLeft = dropdownContainerOffset.left;
    const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const dropdownStyle = {
      top: dropdownContainerOffset.top + dropdownContainerOffset.height,
      left: dropdownContainerOffset.left
    };

    if (containerTop > viewportHeight/2) {
      dropdownStyle.top = 'auto';
      dropdownStyle.bottom = viewportHeight - containerTop;
    }
    this.setState({ dropdownStyle });
  }

  _renderDropdown() {
    const {onSelect, datalist = []} = this.props;

      return (
        <div className="search-dropdown-wrapper" style={this.state.dropdownStyle} onClick={(event) => {alert("Outer wrapper")}}>
          <Card containerStyle={this.cardContainerStyle}>
            <div>
            {"Sample Dropdown"}
            </div>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
  }

  _renderSearchField() {
    const {value, handleSearch} =  this.props;

    return (
      <TextField
        value={value}
        onChange={handleSearch}
        fullWidth={true}
        hintText={resources.BRAND_SEARCH}
        underlineStyle={this.searchFieldUnderlineStyle}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const {isActive, onBlur} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="search-dropdown-container field-wrapper"
        ref={dropdownContainer => this.dropdownContainer = dropdownContainer}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        >
        {this._renderSearchField()}
        {isActive && this._renderDropdown()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SearchDropdown.propTypes = {
  isActive: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  value: React.PropTypes.string,
  datalist: React.PropTypes.array,
  handleSearch: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSelect: React.PropTypes.func
}

export default SearchDropdown;
```

In above code, `_renderDropdown` will only execute when `isActive` is `true`. The compoenent is getting rendered perfectly with all styles when the search field is active. But when this component is rendered, the `onClick` event on the `div` with class `search-dropdown-wrapper` is not working.

I'm not sure where I'm doing mistake. Please let me know if there is any proper way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: the code looks fine, hard to say without debugging, could you make a repository with this problem or put it somewhere like on webpackbin where I would be able to play with it?

Answer (score 4):

I finally made it work.

There is nothing wrong with the arrow function `_renderDropdown` used. The problem is with the `onBlur` event attached to the parent div with class `search-dropdown-container` of `_renderDropdown`. I have removed that `onBlur` event from there and added to `search-dropdown-wrapper` div. Then it started working fine.

What I think is, The `search-dropdown-wrapper` position is `fixed` and so it will not be as part of `search-dropdown-container` technically. So `click` event happening on the  `search-dropdown-wrapper` triggers `onBlur` event of `search-dropdown-container` first. So, the `click` event is not firing on `search-dropdown-wrapper`

Comment: This the most hilarious bugs I have ever seen. Thanks for putting the solution

Answer (score 0):

Please bind `this` to all methods in your class in the constructor like for example -

`constructor(props) {
    this._handleScroll = this._handleScroll.bind(this)
    this._setDropdownBounds = this._setDropdownBounds.bind(this)
}`

FYI

- https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html
- http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/
- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Comment: he is using a special syntax for that `_handleScroll = () => {}`

Comment: Yes you can use arrow functions in class property. But the same should be done for `_setDropdownBounds`, `_renderDropdown`, `_renderSearchField`

Comment: but these methods are called with the right context so it's not a source of the problem.

Comment: No, they are not. For example see `componentDidUpdate`. Under the hood `this._setDropdownBounds()` will be called using the function invocation pattern which will set `this` value inside `_setDropdownBounds` to `window`

Comment: A `componentDidUpdate` has access to the class `this` and every function called inside will also have access to the same context. Look here at the console.log https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPGNyE that I have access to the component scope.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. I misunderstood how react used to auto-bind in `React.creatClass`. You see, the problem of `this` not being bound properly arises when you pass these `callbacks` to `children` components inside of which `this` value is not bound to the proper parent unless you bind it yourself (either by explicitly binding it or by using arrow functions) in the parent component.

Comment: And I misunderstood that events on the `TextField` were not getting triggered. It is actually the `_renderDropdown`'s `onClick`